# C++ pass function into functor

Tags: c++, functor

I have a problem with the using of functors.
Below shows a functor that takes any functions and returns its function value and derivatives.

```
template <class T>
struct Funcd {
    T &func;
    double f;
    Funcd(T &funcc) : func(funcc) {}
    double operator() (double &x)
    {
        return f=func(x);
    }

    void df(double &x, double &df)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Assume I already have a function like

```
double FunctionA(double &x){
    return x*x;
}
```

My question is that I don't know how to make use of this functor.
Can anyone make an example in the main function that uses this functor to find function value and derivative?
Thanks!

Comment: Why did you write a template that you didn't know how to use?

Comment: The implementation of `df` appears to be missing. And why do you pass around `double&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add it to the functor when you create it. Using the same function names as in your example I would do the following:

```
Funcd fd(FunctionA);
```

then you can you `fd` as a function:

```
double v = fd(2);
```

It could be that you have to specify the template argument when creating `fd` though, I haven't compiled or tested this code.

Comment: Class templates cannot deduce arguments (yet), so you have to write `Funcd<double(double &)>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it's right! You are right the argument needs to be specified as Funcd<double(double &)>. Thanks again